# pass data in req.user javascript-express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a simple express server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port =  process.env.PORT || 3000;

var consentRoutes = require('./src/routes/consentRoutes.js');
app.use('/consents', (req, res, next) => {
    req.user="Eleftheria"
    next();
  }
 ,consentRoutes);

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`)
})
```

the file : consentRoutes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const consentControllers = require('../controllers/consentControllers')

//Creates an account access consent : /consents
router.post('/', consentControllers.createConsent);

module.exports = router;
```

and then the controllers file named : consentControllers.js

```
const request = require("request");

//Creates an account access consent: /consents
exports.createConsent = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("user's name is:" );   
  console.log(req.user);
  next();
};
```

My problem is that req.user is never being printed, what is wrong ?  What I want to do is, to pass data in the file : consentControllers.js and be able to use and access them there. I am really new to express and I am still trying to figure out how everything works.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Express.js appends the data in the middleware order call. You assigned `req.user` AFTER consentRoutes middleware execution. The correct is:

```
app.use(
  "/consents",
  (req, res, next) => {
    req.user = "Eleftheria";
    next();
  },
  consentRoutes
);
```

Now, you first append `user` to `req`, then pass to the next middleware `consentRoutes` the req variable with user assigned.

It is worth saying that assign properties directly for req is not a good practice. You should use **res.locals** for it.

Comment: I chaged the code like you told me ( see the edited versio above), but still the code does not work

Comment: I chaged the code like you told me ( see the edited versio above), but still the code does not work

Comment: Are you calling http://localhost:3000/consents with POST method from a Postman for example?